# android With Opencv float mat

Tags: java, c++, opencv

I am working with openCv and android in java and i have some problem on it 
i change c++ with opencv code to java

i just have problem here its about MAT_

```
cv::Mat_<float> measurement(2,1); 
measurement.setTo(cv::Scalar(0));
```

I know the mat in java only Mat name;
but what about

```
Mat_<float>
```

i search but i didnt find any result

any help how to use it in android On java
Or did there are opencv documentation talk about this

Comment: so, you seem to want to use the Kalman filter. just asking, - is that opencv2.4 or 3.0 ?

Comment: its 2.4.10 i try now to use partical filter and kalman filter 

i saw your comment its work why you delete it ?

Comment: afaik, the KalmanFilter is not usable for the java opencv 2.4 wrappers, since some essential Mat's like the measurement Matrix are not setup correctly by default, and you can't set it from java (like it's done in the c++ demos) you'll have to upgrade to opencv3.0 to make proper use of that

Comment: its show to me availble on 2.4.10  also 3.0  didnt support partical filter

Comment: available != working, unfortunately

Comment: again, update to opencv3, use a `MatOfFloat(0,0)` or a Mat(2,1,CvType.CV32F,newScalar(0))` and you're ready to go.

Comment: aha so its just 3.0 
i will change it to 3.0 
InitMatHeader()  did this function available on opencv android ?

Comment: not that i knew. (initMatHeader() is only part of the deprecated c-api, it was **never** used in opencv's java wrappers, - you must have taken that idea from dreaded javacv ;)

Comment: ok thank you @berak ... when i get Reputation  i will vote up to you :P